# Is my iPhone app required to be compatible with 3.5" screens now that the iPhone 6 was released?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm developing an app for the iPhone. its target device when this started was the iPhone 5/5s. Now that the iPhone 6 and 6+ were released, the app is compatible with them. however, i was wondering if supporting old 3.5" displays is required. I'd like to skip that step if at all possible, but i don't want to be rejected by apple for it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple's App Store guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since *iOS 8* supports the *iPhone 4S*, which has a 3.5´´ display, my guess is: yes, this is required for now.

Presumably, once an *iOS* version that drops *iPhone 4S* support is released (possibly *iOS 9*), you could require that version as the minimum *Deployment Target* of your app, and then drop support for 3.5´´ screens.